# calculating correlation

Tags: statistics

If one fair six-sided die is rolled, suppose that $X$ is the total number of even numbers shown and $Y$ is the total number of fives shown.

How can I go about calculating the correlation exactly in terms of $p_1$ and $p_2$?

I was given, Hint: Notice that $E(XY) = 0$. Explain why this is true and use this fact in your calculation.

I'm not sure how to do about this... any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints to start:

- The covariance is $E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])] = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$
- The correlation coefficient is the covariance divided by the product of the standard deviations.
- For a Bernoulli random variable which is $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$, the expectation is $p$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$

Comment: okay I calculated E[x] = 1/2, Var(x) = 1/2, E[Y] = 1/6, Var(Y)= sqrt 5/6.. but then I get the Corr(XY) = 0 but the hint says it should be negative.. any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @ulc8: The covariance is $0-\frac12 \times \frac16 = -\frac{1}{12}$ so the correlation coefficient will also be negative.  And  it the standard deviations not the variances which are $\frac12$ and $\sqrt{\frac{5}{36}}$

Comment: thank you.. that makes much more sense!